# How can I make each object unique when creating an array of objects using array_fill?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an array of objects in Yii2.  However, the problem is that the objects within the array have absolutely no distinction.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
$array1 = array(new Object, new Object, new Object);
$array2 = array_fill(0, 2, new Object);
```

At first glance, they look the same, but the outputs are not.

$array1

```
[
    0 => frontend\models\Object#1
    (
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => []
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => null
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
        [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
        [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
        [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
    )
    1 => frontend\models\Object#2
    (
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => []
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => null
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
        [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
        [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
        [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
    )
    2 => frontend\models\Object#3
    (
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => []
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => null
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
        [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
        [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
        [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
    )
]
```

And here is $array2

```
[
    1 => frontend\models\Object#4
    (
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => []
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => null
        [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
        [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
        [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
        [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
        [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
    )
    2 => frontend\models\Object#4(...)
    3 => frontend\models\Object#4(...)
]
```

Notice the number after "Object" doesn't change in $array2 like it does in $array1.  This is causing some problems for my code. I know I can simply do array_push but this particular array could grow to be quite large and I'd rather not use a loop to create it. If it can be done in a single command, I'd really like to use that method.

Comment: Your problem is that in PHP, objects are implicitly passed by reference so `array_fill` is simply adding the single object passed as the third argument, multiple times. I'd say you're just going to have to use a loop (which I'm sure is what `array_fill` does internally anyway)

Comment: Well that bites... so there's no clever way around this?

Comment: That clever enough? `$array2 = range(0, 2); array_walk($array2, function(&$e) { $e = new Object; });`

Comment: @CBroe which is an implicit loop. No, there's no way around an implicit or explicit loop in userland.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, and as far as you told, the cleaner way of achieving this is still a simple loop:

```
$n = 56; 
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) $array[] = new Object;
```

It is one line solution, and I think it works quite fast... There are many functions for operating on each element of array, but almost all of them works in the way You described. So why not to use simple for loop?

Even if the array is quite big (as you said), there is nothing wrong with this solution I think. It is one line and elegant, and clean. Even when the nerds at http://www.php.net are doing everything they can to make the built in functions work fast, I dont think that any of the build in functions (even if exists) should do it **really** faster. I didn't test the speed, but I'm quite sure there will be almost no difference.

However your question is very good, and thanks to it, I read all the array functions in manual on php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

---

I think the code is clean enough, but I will describe it for others:

```
$array[] = new Object;
```

This appends `new Object` at the end of an `array`.

In that case, it gives an `array` that is filled with `new Object` from `0` to `55`, for example:

```
array[10] // -> some object; 
array[35] // -> another object;
```

---

PS. **Single command (as you said) just look nice.** It doesn't work like a magic command, and almost always there is a huge amount of code "under it". **The only way, using built in functions is better, it is that almost always this prepared "under code" is faster then yours.**

That's why I recommend on going with this easy readable solution, because all array walk functions, etc, have also many, many lines of complicated code inside :).
Which method is faster, only a benchmark can tell, but I can bet that for up to 1000 objects, the difference will be "almost none".

---

*And as far, as there is no dedicated function for that particular example, you must use some "elegant trick" on one of the functions that are optimized for doing something... Let's say else. **This function can work much more slower in that case.***

Comment: Welp, this is close  to what I had planned on doing if I couldn't get array_fill to work. I was going to use array_push, but this is obviously more elegant, but probably wouldn't have made much different speed-wise. Excellent write up and thank you!